# Delay dynamic GUI changes

Tags: java, android, sms, broadcast

Activity description :

The main idea is to have an sms sending list and when user clicks the 'Send' button,  the broadcast receivers start to receive and GUI changes like highlighting the 'Sent/Not sent' member list, updating progress bar , counting etc

Problems : Activity runs for hours and it's very important to save the exact same GUI change in sync with the user's action on the phone

However I have a few problems and th

1. The battery is dead/app crash.

   Solution : Saving each 'send' state to file and loading it the next time when the user runs the app
2. The user hits the back/stop button or has an incoming call / Just wants to surf the web.

   Solution : Maybe keep running it in the background? by using transparent activity ?

*NOTE : its not about the 'save' state or 'restore' state because everything depends on the broadcast receiver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideal way could be

- do the backend logic with broadcast recievers + intent service and log the data in backend
- Use the activity to just display the UI state based on the saved data.

Comment: yes but it wont be online/live gui when user comes back to the activity again ):

Comment: once user comes back to activity - (in onCreate / onResume) repopulate the view with data. That separates out your tasks cleanly

Comment: yes but it wont be online/live gui . . . when user comes back i can  show heme the correct status but the gui will stop changing parallel to broadcast reciver

Comment: service is much better that transparent activity. service also can show UI. Looks like your is a application used for some testing purpose. Go by service then

Comment: https://www.websmithing.com/2011/02/01/how-to-update-the-ui-in-an-android-activity-using-data-from-a-background-service/comment-page-1/#comment-734